# How to count and display user taps in the bar button item?

Tags: iphone

I am developing a project in which the user can add the object to favorite list that is table View. here I adding the object through `rightBarButtonItem`. I wanna show a message if User tap the right BarButton more than one. message is nothing but a `UILabel` that contains text like "Object already exist". please help me to solve this problem. thanks....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might have a method that is executed when the button is tapped where you add the item to your table view. Lets say the method is called `didClickButton`. Have a Bool variable say `isItemAdded` indicating the status of the item. Set it to `NO` initially. when button is pressed check if its `NO`. If `NO` then proceed and set it to `YES` else display "Alert already added"

```
-(void)didClickButton
{
if(!isItemAdded)
{
//code to add to tableview
isItemAdded = YES;
}
else
{
//code to show message or alert
}
}
```

Comment: thanks for the Answer. I done what you have mention but it displaying the message only one time. If I tap more than once, the message is not displaying.

Comment: debug so that you can easily spot what causes the issue. I think you can find the reason

Answer (score 0):

Initiaize a global counter and use it to count the taps by incrimienting it inside the method that is called by your rightBarButtonItem.

```
int tapsCtr =  0;
```

Put this code inside your method:

```
tapsCtr++; 
if(tapsCtr > 1){
      NSLog(@"User tapped more than once"); 
      tapsCtr = 0;
}
```